# AngularJS webapp: how to retrieve a json with the bytes of an image via an http post request

Tags: angularjs, image, http

From an AngularJS webapp I do an http post request like this:

Response Headers:
Content-Type is application/json

Request Headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Form data is:
json:{"id":100,"value":"https://myweb/go/1.0-1/Photo/Spa_03.jpg"}

Response is like:
{"id": 100, "imageBytes": "IMAGE BYTES"} where IMAGE BYTES are the bytes of the image whose URL is supplied in the request.

I get an HTTP success (200) but an error in the angular code (in fromJson / defaultHttpResponseTransform). Error is SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

I suppose that the response content-type is incorrect.
But could someone tell me what I must set ? And how ?

Regards.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can try use base64

Comment: I get the error in the angularJS code before getting back to my own code. Where would you suggest to decode with base64 service ?